# Creating a virtual environment results in the wrong base prefix (Django, Python installation)

Tags: django, installation, pip, radix

I am trying to create a virtual environment following the Django tutorial (official documentation)

When i type "python" at CMD, it shows me the version is 3.6 (python)

However when I follow the steps to create a virutal environment:

1. pip install virtualenvwrapper-win and then
2. mkvirtualenv myproject

It does so...but displays the following message:

```
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python34'
```

I obviously want it to be set up using Python 3.6.

I tried editing the path environmental variable (edit text in the advanced settings), but that didn't work either.

I obviously don't want it using 3.4 version as "DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429)." but cannot figure out how to make it install Django/PIp and everything else in the right version.

Python 3.4 is located in a different place to Python 3.6

I used set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64

to try and set it to the right path (that is where Python 3.6 is installed).

Any suggestions? I have looked through the various questions but this is specific to the correct creation of a virtual env leading on to pip installation and the errors caused by being in the wrong version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `mkvirtualenv myproject --python "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\python.exe" `

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this, but most likely you're calling Python34's `pip`.

`pip.exe` does not reside in `.\Python36_64` folder but in `.\Python36_64\Scripts`. Have you got this folder in `%PATH%`? You can check it with:

```
where pip.exe
```

However, in Windows it's recommended:

- calling `pip` as a module—furthermore you can be sure that you're calling the same version's `pip`.
- invoking Python via [Python's launcher `py.exe`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)—which resides in `C:\Windows\`, is `PATH` agnostic, and allows you to manage multiple versions.

```
py -m pip install <package>
```

Also, since Python 3.6, the recommend way to create virtual environments is through the stdlib's module `venv`:

```
py -m venv c:\path\to\new\venv
```